# Appending a string variable in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm not sure if I have the syntax correct in the code below, I'm trying to append a var to a string parameter within the find function.  I'm trying to search for a unique id within each input element of a particular form.

```
 //Get value attribute from submit button
 var name = $('#myForm').find('input#submitThis').val();

    //Other code that manipulates the name variable

 //Submit button in hidden form
 $('.submitLink').click(function(){
  $('#myForm').find('input#'+name).click();
  return false;
 });
```

The element with a `submitLink` class is supposed to be tied to the submit button in the form.  I don't think I have the syntax correct though, when I go back and click the element that has the `submitLink` class, nothing happens.

Comment: When you run this and it doesn't work, what is the value of name and what is the ID of the input you are trying to trigger a click event from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax appears fine to me. To be sure the selector is what you are expecting it to be, you could do something like this:

```
$('.submitLink').click(function() {
   var selector = 'input#' + name;
   alert(selector);
   /* rest of the code */
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an alert to test the var inside the event handler (and to see that the handler is fired). Also, if you are looking for an element with a specific **id** you don't need to include the element type. Like this:

```
$('.submitLink').click(function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  alert(name);
  $('#' + name, $('#myForm')).click();
});
```

NOTE: If you are trying to find an element by its name rather than ID you must use `$("input[name='foo']")`.

Comment: Thank you both very much David and ayaz.  Appreciate your help, this was exactly what I was looking for.  I was using the wrong attribute, I had the name, when instead I meant to use the id.  Thanks again.